# Refactor: How to use .reduce with an external function?

Tags: javascript, function, dictionary, reduce

hope that you're doing well. I've a question related to the .reduce function. I'm refactoring an elder code and, in order to fulfill the DRY principle, I'd like to know how to create a function that allows my to achieve a 'simple' process from .reduce:

- Group the data by a certain key (`phoNumbId` in the example).
- Sum values of another key (but related to the first key) to summarize both (this key is `mount`).
- Return a dictionary with the grouped key and the added values

To clarify my question, I've this example dictionary:

```
const nexus = [
  { namesId: 1, phoNumbId: 1, country: 'PERU', mount: 1200 },
  { namesId: 1, phoNumbId: 2, country: 'CANADA', mount: 2000},
  { namesId: 2, phoNumbId: 2, country: 'ENGLAND', mount: 3000},
  { namesId: 2, phoNumbId: 3, country: 'RUSSIA', mount: 40000},
  { namesId: 3, phoNumbId: 1, country: 'BELGIUM', mount: 500},
  { namesId: 3, phoNumbId: 2, country: 'SPAIN', mount: 500},
  { namesId: 3, phoNumbId: 3, country: 'PORTUGAL', mount: 2020}
]
```

And the (coded) process that I want to refactor is:

```
var result2 = [];

nexus.reduce(function (res, value) {
        if (!res[value.phoNumbId]) {
            res[value.phoNumbId] = { phoNumbId: value.phoNumbId, mount: 0 };
            result2.push(res[value.phoNumbId])
        }
        res[value.phoNumbId].mount+= value.mount;
        return res;
    }, {});
```

The way that my limited knowledge in JS allows me to code a possible solution then is as follows:

```
function sumAll(firstValue,secondValue,finalArray){
 if (!res[value.firstValue]) {
            res[value.firstValue] = { firstValue: value.firstValue, secondValue: 0 };
            finalArray.push(res[value.firstValue])
        }
        res[value.primerValor].secondValue+= value.secondValue;
        return res;
}

var result2 = [];

nexus.reduce(function (res, value) { sumAll(phoNumbId,mount,result2) }, {});
```

I'd really appreciate anykind of help :)
P.S.: I couldn't think of another title for the question, feel that doesn't summarize the real problem. I accept suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [computed property names](https://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript) - that's using your argument values in bracket notation - to create the object.

```js
const data=[{namesId:1,phoNumbId:1,country:"PERU",mount:1200},{namesId:1,phoNumbId:2,country:"CANADA",mount:2e3},{namesId:2,phoNumbId:2,country:"ENGLAND",mount:3e3},{namesId:2,phoNumbId:3,country:"RUSSIA",mount:4e4},{namesId:3,phoNumbId:1,country:"BELGIUM",mount:500},{namesId:3,phoNumbId:2,country:"SPAIN",mount:500},{namesId:3,phoNumbId:3,country:"PORTUGAL",mount:2020}];

function sumAll(data, first, second) {

  const temp = data.reduce((acc, c) => {
    
    // For convenience assign the object key
    // to the first argument
    const key = c[first];
    
    // If the key doesn't exist on the object
    // add it and assign an object to it
    acc[key] ??= { [first]: key, [second]: 0 };
    
    // Then update the value
    acc[key][second] += c[second];
   
    return acc;
  
  }, {});
  
  // Finally you probably want to return
  // an array of just those objects
  return Object.values(temp);
  
}

console.log(sumAll(data, 'phoNumbId', 'mount'));
console.log(sumAll(data, 'namesId', 'mount'));
```

Additional documentation

- [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)
- [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 1):

Consider your original code (before refactoring) is runnable.

---

Here is the first integration:

```js
var result2 = nexus.reduce(function (res, value) {
    if (!res[value.phoNumbId]) {
        res[value.phoNumbId] = { phoNumbId: value.phoNumbId, mount: 0 };
        res.push(res[value.phoNumbId])
    }

    res[value.phoNumbId].mount += value.mount;
    return res;
}, []);
```

What changed:

- the return from the `reduce` function is assigned directly to `result2`
- the 2nd param of the `reduce` function is the initial value of the `result2` from the origin (in this case, an empty array `[]`)
- the `result2.push(....)` is changed to `res.push(....)`

---

Here is the second integration:

```js
var result = nexus.reduce(function (acc, cur) {
    if (!acc[cur.phoNumbId]) {
        acc[cur.phoNumbId] = { phoNumbId: cur.phoNumbId, mount: 0 };
        acc.push(acc[cur.phoNumbId])
    }

    acc[cur.phoNumbId].mount += cur.mount;
    return acc;
}, []);
```

What changed:

- rename variables:

  - `result2` -> `result`
  - `res` -> `acc` (it stands for `accumulator`)
  - `value` -> `cur` (it stands for `current value`)

---

Here is the third integration

```js
function my_reducer(acc, cur) {
    if (!acc[cur.phoNumbId]) {
        acc[cur.phoNumbId] = { phoNumbId: cur.phoNumbId, mount: 0 };
        acc.push(acc[cur.phoNumbId])
    }

    acc[cur.phoNumbId].mount += cur.mount;
    return acc;
}

var result = nexus.reduce(my_reducer, []);
```

What changed:

- Extract the `no name` function (the one that was passed as the 1st param to the `reduce` function) to a function with a name.

---

It will take time to explain the way the `reduce` function works. You can find out around the internet or other StackOverflow questions/answers.

Here is a short explanation:

Take a look at `var result = nexus.reduce(my_reducer, []);`, consider

- `result` is a soup bowl
- `nexus` is an array of ingredients [ meat,  milk,  egg,  tomato,  potato]
- `reduce` is a cook ‍
- `my_reducer` is a cooker robot
- `[]` is an empty bow

Then 2 params pass to the `my_reducer` (the cooker robot ) are:

- `acc`: the current status of the bowl
- `cur`: the current ingredient we are processing

Thus

> var result = nexus.reduce(my_reducer, []);

similar to

> = [, , , , ].‍(, )

> (current bowl status, current ingredient)

```markdown
+ the soup bowl  is created by using a cooker 
+ to cook all ingredients [, , , , ]
+ that prepared by the cook ‍
+ start with an empty bowl
```

---

How it works:

At the beginning, you have: a cook ‍, a cooker robot , an empty bow

‍(, )

The cook ‍ will loop through each ingredient (follow the order in the array)

1. The cook ‍ picks meat

- (, ) returns () [aka bowl with cooked meat]

2. The cook ‍ picks the next ingredient which is egg

- (, ) returns () [bowl with cooked ...]

3. The cook ‍ picks the next ingredient which is milk

- (, ) returns () [bowl with cooked ...]

4. so on
5. The last ingredient is potato

- just like that we have a bow of all cooked ingredients ()

That is our soup

Comment: I took a couple of hours to read aour answer. Now I understand the syntax of reduce much better! Thanks for taking the time to explain it that way.

Comment: That was really fun to read @Khoa. (PS it should be "Soup Bowl".)